# Using VBA for word to select text and make it bold

Tags: vba, ms-word

I make a several page word document every week. I copy text from a PDF and paste it into a word document, I then format the text that I pasted.

This takes a long time and i would like to automate it.

I need a macro or some code to select specific text, then make that text bold. The specific text i need to bold is what i call a scrap code.

There are 60 different codes. For example "FIPS", or "LILL".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub A()
'
' a Macro
'
'
Dim A(3) As String

A(1) = "code1"
A(2) = "code2"
A(3) = "code3"

For i = 1 To 3
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
       .Forward = True
       .Wrap = wdFindStop
       .Format = False
       .MatchCase = False
       .MatchWholeWord = False
       .MatchWildcards = False
       .MatchSoundsLike = False
       .MatchAllWordForms = False
       .Replacement.Font.Bold = True

       .Execute FindText:=A(i), ReplaceWith:=A(i), Format:=True, _
         Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

HTH!

Edit

To switch dollar amounts to bold

```
Sub a()
'
' a Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "$([0-9.,]{1,})"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok one more thing. I want to bold dollar amounts on the same document. Could I have it look for a dollar sign, then select until there is a space in the document? Every dollar amount on the document starts with a dollar sign so i figured looking for that would be the easy thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I'll be sure to contribute to the community.

Comment: @Aaron I am sure you will. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest recording a macro.
Then do all the modifications and formatting.
Finally, look at the code of the macro and see how it did it.

The one thing you need to figure out is how you logically want to locate the text you want to bold.
Is it a specific line?  Is it at the beginning of a known word?

Once you have that answered, you can combine it with the code of the macro and automate the task.

Comment: I was thinking of making a string array with each of the scrap codes. Perhaps i could use find replace to look for each scrap code in the document and then make it bold.

Dim ScrapCodes as String()= 'all scrap codes
Dim Counter as integer = 0

do until Counter > 'the number of codes
'use counter to call each scrap code in the array
'look for scrap code
'make scrap code bold
'add 1 to counter
end 

It's been a long time since I've programmed, but that is what I was thinking would make sense.