# Go to end of each line and bold text inside parenthesis

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting, format

I need to automate formatting specific words at the end of each line in MS Word. Since I could not record a macro to do the job owing to limitations of Word macros, I have to post it here. All I need is to do the following:-

1. Check each line for a start of (
2. Start selecting the text inside parenthesis (including the parenthesis) till ) is found as end of a sentence
3. Format text to bold
4. Do this till the end of file
5. Exception: Don't format headings which are already bolded and underlined.

How could I do that? Or please rectify my code as it is doing nothing at all.

```
Sub m1()
'
' m1 Macro
'
'
Dim i As Integer
With Selection.Find
For i = 1 To lastRow
 .Forward = True
 .ClearFormatting
 .MatchCase = False
 .Wrap = wdFindContinue
 .Execute FindText:="("
 Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
 Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
 Selection.Font.BoldBi = wdToggle
 Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you run into problems? Keep in mind Stack Overflow is not a "please write all this code for me" website.

Comment: NO I wish to write it myself. Even though I lack much skill of coding in VB. All I need to know is how to do the step 2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457050/using-vba-for-word-to-select-text-and-make-it-bold

Comment: Word does not work with lines. Are those lines being ended with a new line character (Enter key), essentially making those lines paragraphs?

Comment: @ZygD «Word does not work with lines» Word does not *ordinarily* work with lines but can do so if required.

Comment: @Roy If all you're looking for is text inside parentheses, what role do lines ends have? The bolding of text inside parentheses doesn't require a macro.

Comment: @braX check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeeded in building this code:

```
Sub m1()
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
        Do While .Execute(FindText:="(", Forward:=True, MatchWildcards:=False) = True
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
            Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
            Selection.Font.BoldBi = wdToggle
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

It Workded! :) Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1):

You might not need a macro is you know the Style of your document’s body text is always a certain designated style other than a Heading style. Setup your Find and Replace like this:

[image]

If the wildcard code is difficult to read from the screen clip it is: [(]*[)]

Comment: It says: Nothing found!

Comment: Is the style name of the text in your document Normal. Change the Style Name in the search to whatever your Body Text style name is in your document.

Answer (score 0):

MS Word does not work with lines. The following VBA code will find paragraphs which end with parentheses and bold them together with the contents.

```
Sub Bold_ending_parentheses()
  Dim par As Word.Paragraph
  Dim str As String
  Dim closes As Byte
  Dim opens As Long

  For Each par In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    str = StrReverse(par.Range.Text)
    closes = InStr(Left(str, 4), ")")
    If closes Then
      opens = InStr(str, "(")
      If opens Then
        
        With par.Range
          .Find.Text = StrReverse(Mid(str, closes, opens - closes + 1))
          Do
            .Find.Execute
            If .Find.Found Then .Font.Bold = True
          Loop While .Find.Found
        End With
        
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

EDIT:

An example of using Find and Replace. Using this, all the text in parentheses is bolded (not taking into account the requirement of being at the end of paragraph/line):

```
Sub ApplyBoldWithinParentheses()
   With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Text = "[(]*[)]"
      .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
      .Format = True
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Looping through the paragraphs in a document will be painfully slow. Your use of `Find` is illogical as you are using it to find text that you have already found. The loop makes even less sense as the text to be found can only exist once in the paragraph. The two calls to `InStr` have already given you the start and end position for the range that needs formatting. But a much better way of achieving this would be to use Find and Replace with wildcards.

Comment: It was bit difficult to comprehend for a beginner like me. I have successfully made one down here. Thank you for paying heed though!

Comment: @TimothyRylatt - pls suggest a better alternative solving all the issues instead of just pointing at them. I will understand better the code than the text.

Comment: @ZygD - I have edited your answer with an example