# Word VBA bold specific strings of text (sentences)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some specific things I need to automatically bold and am having issues coming up with the right code for this... Below is an example:

Product Name:

Customer Account/Name:

Description of Issue:

So, what I need is only bold the above and nothing after the ":", example:

**Product Name:** Tech Tools

**Customer Account/Name:** Federation of Planets

**Description of Issue:** NCC-1701 leaking

So, all of my VBA experience comes from Excel... Which I stupidly started this in excel and then realized that wouldn't work and was like "Oh, I can just use my vba from Excel in Word!" No... no I can't...

Here is my Excel VBA:

```
Sub Find_and_Bold()
Dim rCell As Range, sToFind As String, iSeek As Long
Dim Text(1 To 33) As String
Dim i As Integer


Text(1) = "Product Name:"
Text(2) = "Project ID and/or URL:"
Text(3) = "Permission to join project?"
Text(4) = "Permission to join Account as Admin?"
Text(5) = "No. of Users on Project:"
Text(6) = "Company/Account Name:"
Text(7) = "Reported by:"
Text(8) = "Reporting User Role in Project:"
Text(9) = "Platform, Version, OS Version:"
Text(10) = "Which platform does this organization/user mainly use?"
Text(11) = "Can the agent repro in test project?"
Text(12) = "Is this related to a third-party integration? (If so, please provide name):"
Text(13) = "What is the company and project name in the third-party software?"
Text(14) = "Has the reporter been able to perform this action with no issues in the past?"
Text(15) = "Pype-Spec Version Name (if applicable):"
Text(16) = "Salesforce ID:"
Text(17) = "Description of Issue:"
Text(18) = "Steps to Reproduce:"
Text(19) = "1."
Text(20) = "2."
Text(21) = "3."
Text(22) = "4."
Text(23) = "Expected Behavior:"
Text(24) = "Observed Behavior"
Text(25) = "Additional Observation/Notes"
Text(26) = "Company/Account name:"
Text(27) = "Can the agent repro in customer project?"
Text(28) = "Is this related to a third party integration?"
Text(29) = "Pype-Spec version name (if applicable):"
Text(30) = "Has the customer provided screenshots/screen- recordings?"
Text(31) = "Description of issue:"
Text(32) = "# of Users on Project:"
Text(33) = "# of Users on Project:"



For Each rCell In Range("A1:A100")
    For i = LBound(Text) To UBound(Text)
        sToFind = Text(i)
        iSeek = InStr(1, rCell.Value, sToFind)
    Do While iSeek > 0
        rCell.Characters(iSeek, Len(sToFind)).Font.Bold = True
        iSeek = InStr(iSeek + 1, rCell.Value, sToFind)
    Loop
Next i
Next rCell

Call DeleteBlankRows

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes you can.  Just add a reference to Word in your excel VBA Ide, open a word document via excel VBA and away you go.

Comment: the word specific object model is pretty different from Excel -e.g. how to use the range-object etc. But why don't you just record a macro while doing a replace for those prefixes and replace them with bold font. then you can start from there in word vba

Comment: VBA is the same across all office products, only the application object model differs (worksheets vs documents etc).

Comment: Thanks for the replies...

freeflow, I don't believe this is a viable answer, as my excel VBA is looking at cell ranges and I do not know how to translate that to Word.

Ike, I was thinking that but it would still add a lot of tedious work and there are going to be a lot of changes I will have to make later... My excel VBA made it super simple and making changes down the road less taxing...

Comment: @KostasK. I am aware, however I am completely unaware of the differences for Word. for example how would any of this translate into Word??:

Comment: Sub Find_and_Bold()

Dim rCell As Range, sToFind As String, iSeek As Long

Dim Text(1 To 3) As String

Dim i As Integer


Text(1) = "Product Name:"

Text(2) = "Project ID and/or URL:"

Text(3) = "Permission to join project?"

For Each rCell In Range("A1:A100")
 For i = LBound(Text) To UBound(Text)
   sToFind = Text(i)
    iSeek = InStr(1, rCell.Value, sToFind)
     Do While iSeek > 0
       rCell.Characters(iSeek, Len(sToFind)).Font.Bold = True
       iSeek = InStr(iSeek + 1, rCell.Value, sToFind)
  Loop
  Next i
Next rCell
End Sub

Comment: @KostasK. Recording a macro, while it may produce the same results, will not give the answer that I am really looking for... There's about 33 different lines that I need to do this for (with more to come), my example only had 3... I'll modify my original post to see if it will so what I am trying to do from the Excel VBA I have.

Comment: @KostasK. But I need help in this case... I am MORE than happy to continue to learn how to use VBA in Word, but I have something that I need to do now so I am asking for help. If you are not able or willing to provide it please move on.

Comment: Do some research, plenty of answers for this topic here in SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457050/using-vba-for-word-to-select-text-and-make-it-bold

Comment: @KostasK. That actually had EXACTLY what I need. Thank you.

Comment: The simple approach would be to use a table in Word and set the first column to be bold.

Comment: You should be using a character or paragraph style in Word to hold your formatting that you are applying.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and always fully qualify your references before move the code for the other Office App. For example, Word and Excel have a `Range` object; when copy code between this two, the code will refer to different objects and runtime errors - compile if u are lucky - will appear.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you could do the lot without VBA, just using a *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = [!^13]@[:\?.]
Replace = ^&
```

and:

```
Find = [!^13][1-4].
Replace = ^&
```

with the replacement font attribute set to Bold or, better still, to the 'Strong' character Style.

The only string that might be missed is 'Observed Behavior' - because in your code it lacks a terminating ':'.

The above can, of course, be turned into VBA.